# Ext JS 3: Get data from fileuploadfield

Tags: javascript, file-upload, extjs, extjs3

I am using Ext.ux.FileUploadField in Ext JS 3.3.1. I need to get the file data from the form. Does anyone know if this is possible without submitting the form? I can see the filename but not the file data...

Thanks.

Comment: What server side framework/language are you using?

Comment: Java, Seam, etc. I was hoping to be able to do this client-side though. But if that's not possible, I'll make a server-side solution.

Comment: Have you tried swfupload? That should be the best solution for such cases. but, remember... sometime swf version in any browsers is varies.. that could be make an error for the user... Safest way is use server-side

Answer (score 1):

```
// get a handle to the FileUploadField component (e.g. by ID)
var fp = Ext.getCmp('fileUploadField');

//add a handler to FileUploadField's fileselected event
fp.on('fileselected', this.onFileUploadFieldFileSelected, this);



// 'fileselected' event handler
onFileUploadFieldFileSelected : function(fp, fileName) {
    // get a handle to the selected file
    var selectedFile = fp.fileInput.dom.files[0];

    // read the contents of the file using FileReader and display content here
}
```